# ShareKit linker failed

Tags: ios, xcode, sharekit

I am having a linker problem when importing the ShareKit sdk:

[image: Screenshot of IDE showing error message]

I have no idea what the problem is.

[image: Close-up screenshot showing folder structure]

Comment: Did you use Google in order to give yourself some ideas?

Comment: yes to all comments  http://getsharekit.com/install/

Comment: Looks like an error with the user search paths in your project...

Comment: it automatically looks into the folder you are in.. so you don't need to specify the whole path url.. just provide the url of the path in your folder...

Comment: no i didn't understand, what url? I have all the files and this folder in the project, see the edit

Comment: which sharekit are you using? Use Sharekit 2.0....

Comment: the most recent you can download from the website

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20580/discussion-between-lakesh-and-alessandro)

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Close as not a real question, because a screenshot of an error message too small to read is, frankly, not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Sharekit2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) instead and follow the instructions to install... you should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

You had to link the .m files to your project like this:

That was mostly my issue with "undefined symbols for arm7..."

So what you have to do is: Go to target summary -> build phases -> compile sources -> add the .m files of the one you had added.
[image]

Hope that helped.